# How to properly tokenize column in pandas?

Tags: pandas, nltk, tokenize

I am trying to solve tokenization problem in my dataset with comments from social media. I want to tokenize, lemmatize, remove punctuations and stop-words from the pandas column. I am struggling how to do it for each of the comment. I receive the following error when trying to get tokens:

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk
...
merged['message_tokens'] = merged.apply(lambda x: nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(x['Clean_message']), axis=1)

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

When I am trying to tell pandas that I am passing it a string object, it gives me the following error message:

```
merged['message_tokens'] = merged.apply(lambda x: nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(x['Clean_message'].str), axis=1)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `x['Clean_message']` needs to be a `string`. Hard to advise you unless you show what it is now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `astype` to force the column type to string

```py
merged['Clean_message'] = merged['Clean_message'].astype(str)
```

If you want to look at what's wrong in original column, you can use

```py
m = merged['Clean_message'].apply(type).ne(str)
out = merged[m]
```

`out` dataframe contains the rows where the type of `Clean_message` column is not string.